# How do I display two messages with a delay in between?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

When the user presses a button I want to display two messages where the second message displays a few seconds after the first.  The first message should be left alone while the second one displays.  So here are the steps.

1. User presses button
2. Message 1 displays
3. Wait a few seconds
4. Message 2 displays under message 1

I've searched quite a bit but no suggestion is working.  I've tried various techniques about accessing a property on the message element to force it to be drawn.  However nothing is working for displaying a second message after a delay while leaving the first message on the screen.  Can someone solve this with a working example for IE 11?

The following code doesn't work.

```
<body>
    <div id="message1"></div>
    <div id="message2"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#message1').html("first");
        waitThreeSeconds();
        $('#message2').html("second");
    </script>

</body>
```

This code also doesn't work.

```
<body>
    <div id="message1"></div>
    <div id="message2"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#message1').html("first");
        $('#message1').css('height', 'auto');
        $('#message1').height();

        waitThreeSeconds();

        $('#message2').html("second");
        $('#message2').css('height', 'auto');
        $('#message2').height();
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body>
    <div id="message1"></div>
    <div id="message2"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#buttonid').on('click', function() {
                $('#message1').html("first");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#message2').html("second");
                },3000); //second message will appear 3 seconds later
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fwgu1guf/

Answer (score 0):

try

```html
<div id="message1"></div>
<script>
    $('#message1').html('first');
    setTimeout(function(){$('#message1').html('second')}, 3000);
</script>
```